# Regular expression implementation that can be use for gcc4.8

Tags: c++, regex

Regular expressions will not work on gcc4.8 based on what I found out.
During cross compile I encountered run time errors with regards to regular expressions.
Do you know other ways how can i work with regex at gcc4.8?
I am thinking of creating my own but I wander if there is already available that can be use.

Comment: I assume you're thinking of the C++11 [standard library regex functionality](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex)? Then as I recollect you can't use them as that version of GCC doesn't implement it. What is the reason you're using (the now *ancient*) version 4.8? Why can't you update your compiler to something more modern that at least support all of C++11?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: Why not just assume there _is_ a valid reason behind this? I would think the poster knows how to install or build a newer version of gcc. One reason (just as an example) of the top of my head: until not too long ago `manylinux` i686 CentOS images shipped with gcc 4.8.

Comment: Thank you for checking on my question. The program will run on boards with gcc4.8 requirement. It is not a choice to upgrade the version.

Comment: @steiryx Then you simply can't use the C++11 regex facilities. There are other regex libraries, for example the POSIX regex library which should be standard in all Linux systems. But then you need to port the code you have.

Comment: Have you checked some older version of boost::regex library which might still be supported and has a cross section with your compiler requirement (gcc 4.8)?

Comment: boost::regex is largely a drop in replacement for std::regex

Comment: @Peter it's reasonably [trivial](https://www.softwarecollections.org/en/scls/rhscl/devtoolset-8/) to install a more recent version of gcc on centos

Comment: *"run on boards with gcc4.8 requirement"* Not sure if's viable for you, but could use a newer GCC and statically link the standard library? It worked for me in a similar situation.

Comment: Thanks for sharing some information. I am not pushing to use regex in gcc4.8, that is why I am asking for an alternative. I tried to use boost, but somehow during runtime it shows error that the shared object for that library cannot be found.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I am not familiar with POSIX regex library. Do you mean it will work on gcc4.8 but command will be different so I have to somehow modify my regex processing. Is my understanding correct?

Answer (score 1):

### [GCC 4.8](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.8/) is really old (and no more maintained in 2020).

Consider updating it -in October 2020- to [GCC 10](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-10/) (whose source code you could compile) and read documentation about [invoking GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Invoking-GCC.html) and using [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/). I suggest compiling with `g++ -Wall -Wextra -g` using a *recent* [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/).

Read at least the C++11 standard [n3337](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf) and a good [C++ programming book](https://stroustrup.com/programming.html) and more about the [`#include <regex>` standard header](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex).

On Linux and POSIX systems, you could use [regex(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/regex.3.html). The source code is available, since open source (in e.g. the [GNU libc](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/) or the [musl-libc](https://musl.libc.org/)) and with permission you can adapt it to your working context.

You could also use [Qt](https://qt.io/) or [POCO](https://pocoproject.org/). Both have some regular expressions facilities and are open source. So you can study their source code implementation of [regular expressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) and their relation to [push down automata](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pushdown_automaton). Read also about [recursive descent parsers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_descent_parser) and consider using parser generators (if allowed) such as [GNU bison](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/), [flex](https://github.com/westes/flex/), or [ANTLR](https://antlr.org/). If performance is a major concern, consider using (with permission) code generating libraries like [libgccjit](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/jit/), [asmjit](https://github.com/asmjit/asmjit), [GNU lightning](https://www.gnu.org/software/lightning/), [tinycc](https://github.com/TinyCC/tinycc).

Of course, read the [*Dragon book*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compilers:_Principles,_Techniques,_and_Tools). It explains the basic concepts for regular expressions. Read also recent papers to ACM [SIGPLAN](https://sigplan.org/) conferences.

If your management requires specifically [GCC 4.8](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.8/) (I would consider changing jobs with such a stupid requirement - since [cross compiling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_compiler) GCC 10 is quite easy, and GCC improved a lot in five years), you should at least ask permission to compile some *existing* regular expression open source libraries (you'll find many of them on [github](https://github.com/) or [gitlab](https://gitlab.com/)), or in [boost](https://www.boost.org/).

Consider of course asking permission to use a *recent* [Clang](https://clang.llvm.org/) compiler (you could compile it from its source code, since it is [open source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_source)), the [Clang static analyzer](https://clang-analyzer.llvm.org/), and perhaps [Frama-C++](https://frama-c.com/), and to read [this draft](http://starynkevitch.net/Basile/bismon-chariot-doc.pdf) report. See also the [CHARIOT](https://www.chariotproject.eu/) and [DECODER](https://www.decoder-project.eu/) European projects.

PS. Cross-compiling GCC 10 takes one or two days (if you are a newbie). Writing your regular expression library could take you several weeks.

Comment: Thank you for checking on my question. But this is not possible, gcc4.8 is strictly required.

Comment: Old embedded platforms often use old compilers.

Comment: But old embedded platforms are generally used with cross-compilers, and your management could give you permission to recompile (or buy) a newer variant of it. Specifically, [GCC 10](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-10/) can be compiled to target *many* old embedded platforms